# Laravel RequirePassword Middleware not working in laravel 7.3x

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use the laravel confirm password middleware on one of my routes but i keep getting the error

> Route [password.confirm] not defined.

I've tried adding the blade file manually in the auth/passwords/confirm.blade.php but its still not working.

find my code attached below.

```
  class UserController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware(['auth', 'password.confirm']);
        }
```

I checked the kernel file and it is already defined in the $routeMiddleware as seen below.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'password_expired' => \App\Http\Middleware\PasswordExpired::class,
    ];
```

can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've gone through the documentation and it all seems straightforward but when i do it something is a miss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: error saying about route .Route [password.confirm] not defined. so check anywhere you have used route('password.confirm')

Comment: Take a look at the documentation which lays out how to set this up: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#the-password-confirmation-form

Comment: @JohnLobo from all the tutorials and even in the documentation, there is no mention of creating the required routes or blade files. The necessary views seem to be created automatically, or so it seems to me.
After researching i saw other articles talking about creating the blade file manually but that didnt work either.

Comment: @AlexHarris i am currently using laravel 7.3 in the project and when i check the documentation, they only have a brief section about it and it all seems straight forward. I figured i should ask on here in case i missed something